# wget doesn't speak english anymore

Tags: wget

All of a sudden, my wget installation started talking to me in Italian (when I do --help or in other interactions). I can understand it, but I have everything set in English and I'd prefer to keep that language. Any idea what's going on.

I'm under macOS 10.13.4 and I've wget 1.19.5 installed via Homebrew.

The problem occurs only with a couple of admin users, when I run it under my regular user, it keeps speaking English.

`locale` output seems fine.

Comment: Look into your environment with `printenv`

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, regular user has LANG=en_GB.UTF-8, root user had it unset and wget takes Italian as default, I have no clue why. wget seems the only command behaving like this (internal default?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering myself: As [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) suggested, I used the `printenv` command to see that the LANG variable is unset and that Italian is taken as default in such a case. so I just put `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` in my `/etc/profile` (actually in a script under `/etc/profile.d`). I've no idea why all of a sudden it takes such a default. My system is configured as English with Italian keyboard layout.

Comment: This still doesn't answer why `wget` is in Italian albeit there is no environment variable that says so. I am experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: @adib, still no idea why. Maybe it's taking some other variable: as I said, my system has an Italian keyboard layout. I hardly have anything else in Italian (apart from caches and cookies from Italian web sites and a number of texts/emails/etc).

Comment: @zakmck This question on AskDifferent might help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21096/where-does-lang-variable-gets-set-in-mac-os-x/23175

Comment: @Nzall, thanks. I remember I had to set OS variables to EN, don't know why they were changed and where.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem here. (wget respondes in german)
In my case - deleting the secondary language (which was in my case german) from 
System-Preferences->Language and Region->Preferend Language
seems to solve the problem. (There is now a single ''English'' entry).

Comment: Ahh! That might explain something: I had secondary lang too and maybe not all applications recognise EN_GB as primary,  (ie, the true English :-D ), only EN_US.